# Webview loads again and again in listview

Tags: android, webview

I am using webview as an list element but it reloads as list is scrolling,
how to avoid reloading of webview. can we cache webview data.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

we can cache the web view content by using any of the following codes.

```
webview.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);

webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
```